# Diff between two PostgreSQL schemas to update script

Tags: database

Let’s say I have PostgreSQL DB A running on production.

Then I’m on a branch and I’ve made some changes on DB A, turning into DB B.

Now I want to generate an update script from A to B.

Is there any tool for this? How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of tools called 'pgdiff' which does exactly this, implemented in various languages - it looks like there's the original Ruby version, and a Go version (and Node, Python...). Pick which ever one fits your language of choice, I guess.